# How to observe state of third party application started using Intent Action View in Android?

Tags: android, security, encryption

I have an application that downloads encrypted pdf files from server. Then when user chooses to read pdf, file will be decrypted and opened with whatever suitable application on user's device is found.

How do I know when 
user goes back from application
or switches to another application 
or presses home button, 
so I can delete decrypted file stored on device?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a memory stream or bytes array to send to the third-party app instead of the file path and then delete the file stored in the device and when the third party gets closed will not be able to re-open the file anymore