# How to restrict file copying shared using Content Provider in Android?

Tags: android, security

Is it possible to forbid making copies of files for third party applications (like adobe reader), that I am using to open pdf files stored in internal memory of my application?

Comment: No, you can't. You can only avoid writing on the file, but if you allow the open and read operation, you can't forbid the other app to copy its content.

Comment: I thought so :( . So only solution is to use some in-app pdf reader right?

Comment: If it's a pdf you can use some password to avoid to print, copy and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. If you hand bytes over to a third-party app, that third-party app can do what it wants with those bytes.

> So only solution is to use some in-app pdf reader right?

This will not completely stop people from copying your PDFs. However, it will limit attacks to those who have rooted their devices, which is probably under 1% of users.

Comment: What if I store encrypted PDFs into internal app memory. Then when user selects to read file, app will decrypt it, store it in external memory and display it using third party app. As soon as third party reader will get out of foreground(back button, home button etc.) my app will delete this decrypted file. I know that for rooted devices even this is not 100% solution. The problem here is how to know when gets pdf reader closed (paused)?

Comment: I asked another question about observing the state of app [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975533/how-to-observe-state-of-third-party-application-started-using-intent-action-view). I would be thankful if someone has an answer.